# What is the Samsung account on Android Phones for and what does it sync?

Tags: samsung, google-account, accounts, cloud

What is the purpose of the samsung account on my android phone? Does it make sense to use it and what does it sync to the cloud?

If I use a google account, isn't that basically enough? Do they interfere with each other?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the purpose of the samsung account on my android phone?

According to [MySamsung](https://mysamsung.com/nz/):

> Your Samsung account is a free integrated membership service that enables you to use Samsung services on smartphones, tablets, websites, TVs and other devices. Enjoy various Samsung services through your Samsung account, without having to sign up for each service separately.

> Does it make sense to use it

Using it provides according to [Samsung](https://www.samsung.com/us/samsung-account-benefits/) the benefits listed below. Whether it makes sense or not depends on whether you believe will add something to your experience while using a Samsung device.

> - A single ID for access, order tracking and support for all of your products
> - Exclusive services like Samsung Pay, Samsung+ and Samsung Health
> - Gift cards, special offers and more with Samsung Rewards
> - Product news and discounts from Samsung.com
> - Tips and tricks sent directly to your inbox for your registered products
> - With a Samsung Account, you are auto-enrolled into Samsung Rewards so you earn points from your purchases on Samsung.com and in the Shop Samsung app to redeem toward products and more.
>     = With a mobile device, you get access to apps and services that also earns you points to use for great rewards.

> and what does it sync to the cloud?

It can sync your files, pictures, SMS, etc. You will select what you want to sync.

> If I use a google account, isn't that basically enough? Do they interfere with each other?

Yes, using a Google account is enough if you don't care about the benefits and the fact that some services offered are just redundant. But note that some updates may come only from Samsung store; and to use Samsung store, you need a Samsung account.

I don't think they interfere with each other but I might be wrong.